# A Jacobian-type criterion for Zariski open algebras

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let's say that a map $A\to B$ of commutative rings is a *Zariski open algebra* if the corresponding map on spectra $\operatorname{Spec}(B)\to \operatorname{Spec}(A)$ is an open immersion of schemes.

If $A\to B$ is a map of commutative rings such that $$B=A[x_1,\dots,x_n]/(f_1,\dots,f_m),$$ with $0\leq m\leq n,$
we have a Jacobian criterion for smoothness (resp. étaleness) that tells us that $B$ is smooth (resp. étale) if the image of the Jacobian determinant of the family $\{f_i\}_{i=1}^m$ with respect to the first $m$ indeterminates $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^m$ in $B$ is invertible (resp. in the case $m=n$).

So what I'm wondering is if there is a further condition that we can use to see when such a presentation in the case $n=m$ is actually a Zariski open algebra.   That is, suppose we're given a family $\{f_1,\dots,f_n\} \subset A[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ that satisfies the Jacobian criterion for étaleness.  Can we see when such a presentation is actually a Zariski open algebra?

Comment: $A \to B$ is an open algebra if and only if it is both flat of finite presentation and an epimorphism in the category of commutative rings. See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/230528/11640). So if you know it is étale then it remains only to check that it is an epimorphism.

Answer (score 2):

As an open immersion is equivalent to a universally injective etale morphism ([Stacks 025G](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/025G)), our goal is to figure out when a morphism is universally injective. A morphism is universally injective precisely when it is injective and every field extension $k(f(x))\to k(x)$ is purely inseparable ([Stacks 01S4](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01S4)), so combining this with the fact that every such field extension associated to an etale map is finite separable ([Stacks 02GL](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02GL)), one must check that your map is injective on topological spaces and gives isomorphisms of residue fields.

(A small quibble: your specification of the first $m$ indeterminants is not quite accurate - one should say that either the Jacobian has rank $m$ or one can choose a presentation so that that the first $m$ indeterminates satisfy the condition you write.)

Comment: I didn't say 'only if', so I think it's alright as a sufficient condition (this was my intention).  Also, this isn't really the kind of thing I had in mind.  I was more wondering if there's an explicit algebraic expression in terms of the presentation that is dispositive.  If you think of it the way Zhen Lin mentions, I'm asking if we can find some expression (complex, invariant, whatever) coming from the polynomials that will ensure that the multiplication map exhibits the tensor square of $B=A[x_1,\dots,x_n]/(f_1,\dots,f_n)$ over A as isomorphic to B.